# how to make a simple list of products?

Tags: product-list

I want to make a simple list or table of products, belonging to a set category.

Currently, this kind of works if I use:

{{block  type="catalog/product_list"  category_id="173" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

However, I want a bare-bones list of names, that hyperlink to the product pages (no images, icons, etc)

What would be a solution here? Create a custom list.phtml page, edit the code to output a simple list, and reference that instead? Is that '*legal*' - code/system wise?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list.phtml in your own theme (app/design/frontend/THEME/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml) and modify the file to suit your needs. Technically it will be considered a clean approach since it wont be modifying any core files.

Comment: Just to tack on:  I wouldn't override the regular list.phtml, rather make new ones.  e.g. `catalog/product/list_nomedia.phtml` or something.  That way you preserve the standard product listing but can have other types as well.