# how to show all products in a list

Tags: product-list

[In a previous question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23546/how-to-make-a-simple-list-of-products/23549#23549), I was trying to create a block which would show all products for that category - which now works. Yippee!

However, the problem now is - while I was able to create a 'simple list' by removing the formatting from the standard list.phtml, I still get the pagination etc with the tool bar.

If I hide or remove the toolbar, this still only shows the first 10 (or whatever is set in config) products. I don't want to change this globally, only in the block.

So the question is, how can I adjust my new simple-list.phtml to show all products by default?

(code is below)

```
<?php
/**
 * Show all products in a simple list - template
 */
?>

<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
?>

<?php if ($_collectionSize && $tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_above_collection')): ?>
    <div class="block_category_above_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!$_collectionSize): ?>
    <?php if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_above_empty_collection')): ?>
        <div class="block_category_above_empty_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="note-msg empty-catalog"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>

<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
    $helpLabels = $this->helper('ultimo/labels');
    $helpTemplate = $this->helper('ultimo/template');
    $helpImg = $this->helper('infortis/image');

    //Hide the toolbar?
    $hideToolbar = false;
    if ($this->getHideToolbar())
    {
        $hideToolbar = true;
    }
?>

<div class="category-products">
    <?php if (!$hideToolbar): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): //List mode ?>

    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ul class="products-list<?php if($listClasses) echo $listClasses; ?>" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php //Product description ?>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <p><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></p>

                </div>
            </div> 
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>  

    <?php else: //Grid mode ?>
        <!-- deleted grid mode section  -->
    <?php endif; //end: if grid mode ?>

    <?php if (!$hideToolbar): ?>
        <div class="toolbar-bottom">
            <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_collectionSize && $tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_below_collection')): ?>
    <div class="block_category_below_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem was pointed [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/296237/) and Marius solved it. I recommend you to read the full thread since there are a few answers with info.

Comment: thanks. I also found this site: http://krcodex.blogspot.de/2013/05/get-all-product-collection-in-magento.html, and by using the code there - I got it working very easily. Thanks!

Comment: Your link is dead, you should have included the infos in your post.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: [using this link](http://krcodex.blogspot.de/2013/05/get-all-product-collection-in-magento.html), I leveraged the code to create the solution below that works nicely.**

```
<?php
/**
 * Show all products in a simple list - template
 */
?>

<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();
?>

<?php if ($_collectionSize && $tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_above_collection')): ?>
    <div class="block_category_above_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!$_collectionSize): ?>
    <?php if ($tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_above_empty_collection')): ?>
        <div class="block_category_above_empty_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="note-msg empty-catalog"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>

<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
    $helpLabels = $this->helper('ultimo/labels');
    $helpTemplate = $this->helper('ultimo/template');
    $helpImg = $this->helper('infortis/image');

?>

 <!-- just hacking a test  -->
<?php
       $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setOrder('name', 'asc'); 

       //getting the product collection, results are ordered by product name

      foreach($product_collection as $_product)
       {
           ?><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?> - </a><?php
           echo "Product ID: ";
           echo $_product->getId() . " - ";
           echo "SKU: ";
           echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSKU() , 'sku'). "<br />";
       }
?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($_collectionSize && $tmpHtml = $this->getChildHtml('block_category_below_collection')): ?>
    <div class="block_category_below_collection std"><?php echo $tmpHtml; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: OK, nightmare... this works on my localhost.. but on my live server, it shows the Product ID, but for the other variables - nothing. What could be the cause of that?